# How to express $n \times n$ matrix multiplication in triangular matrix multiplications.

Tags: linear-algebra

### *This is a homework question*.

First I apologize for the vagueness of the title of this problem, so I'll  first includes the raw homework problem here:

*Proof that if we can perform multiplication of two triangular matrices in time $O(T(n))$, then we can perform the multiplication of two regular matrices in $O(T(n) + n^2)$.*

---

This is what I wanted for "express $n \times n$ matrix multiplication in triangular matrix multiplications."

What I could think of is using block matrix multiplication of two triangular matrix:
$$
\left[~\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  . &  \\
  . & .
  \end{matrix}
   \\
\hline
  \begin{matrix}
  .&. \\
  .&.
  \end{matrix}&
  \begin{matrix}
  . &  \\
  . & .
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}~\right] \times 
\left[~\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  . &  \\
  . & .
  \end{matrix}
   \\
\hline
  \begin{matrix}
  .&. \\
  .&.
  \end{matrix}&
  \begin{matrix}
  . &  \\
  . & .
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}~\right]
$$

Assign a name for each sub-block:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  A \\
\hline
  B & C
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  D \\
\hline
  E & F
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  AD \\
\hline
  BD+CE & CF
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $A,D,C,F$ are lower triangular matrices, $B,E$ are regular matrices.  I don't know what to do with the $BD+CE$. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I just realized that it must refer to the fact that each matrix has a $QR$ factorization into an orthogonal matrix times a triangular matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't figured the solution yet, I've thought for many factorization methods, but most of them seems to be $O(n^3)$, does that means the factorizations cannot be utilized because of the $O(n^2)$ restriction?